# Suggested Edit Queue v2.0

Tags: script, editing

### The Sales Pitch

[image]

This user script enhances the suggested edit queue to remove the usability annoyances we all know and <s>love</s> hate.

- [Suggested Edits will **not** jump to the top when casting the deciding vote.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow) They fade out instead.
- [Suggested Edits you've already voted on are hidden on successive page loads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/97920/can-the-suggested-edit-page-not-show-the-edits-youve-already-voted-on).
- [Adds an "Ignore" option to a suggested edit.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/84102/add-ignore-button-to-suggested-edits) Suggestions you've ignored are hidden on successive page loads.
- [Additions and deletions in a title are mangled together and are hard to understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/112724/please-keep-title-edits-display-consistent-with-content-edits). They're shown side by side.

Added bonus:

- Suggested Edits which have already been voted on by another user are automatically listed first
- Auto-updater built-in, so you'll get new features automatically
- Individual features can be toggled on and off via preferences shown at the bottom of the edit queue.

### Install

[Click here to download and install](https://github.com/downloads/mattlunn/se-edit-queue/se-edit-queue-install.user.js)

### Source Code

The source code is available on [Github](https://github.com/mattlunn/se-edit-queue/). Fork, submit issues, and add pull requests as much as you want.

Released under the [MIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) license, so do whatever you want with it.

### Roadmap

1. Allow clearing of Ignored edits

### Contact

Created by me, [Matt Lunn](http://mattlunn.me.uk). Contact me via contact@mattlunn.me.uk (although I can't see why you'd want to do ;)).

Comment: This is awesome! Can you make it so the improve button works without navigating away too, or alternatively can be middle clicked like a link rather than a button to open in a new tab. (I.e. straight to the edit page rather than via the permalink)

Comment: Any chance you could make the "ignore" button the 4th one rather than the first one? It turns out I've learned the position of the buttons rather well and I've twice hit approve when I meant to reject.

Comment: @Flexo: It looks like the SE Engine doesn't support inline editing of suggested edits, but I'll look at middle-clicking the improve option!

Comment: @Flexo: Mmm, might need more convincing on that one... I've got used to it on the left now ;)... when I originally added it, it was 4th, but in my head I had named the fields from the right, not the left so had the apposite annoyance to what you're experiencing...

Comment: I can't say I'm enamored with the new beta interface. Sadly, the most important part of your script (moving edits to the top once you've acted on them) stopped working (Chrome 20) about the time `/review-beta` was introduced. Is there any chance to make it work again?

Answer (score 3):

## THANK YOU

Thank you, thank you, thank you! Having a consistent response to validating an edit, and not seeing the edits I've already reviewed over and over, makes reviewing suggested edits so much less painful.

---

There's a quoting bug when a title contains characters that are active in HTML is moved to the top. This is how [Executing  elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml/2967069#2967069) appears after I've acted on it:

[image: collapsed title]

Comment: `@`Gilles: This should now be fixed in the userscript version. If you un-install the Chrome Extension and then click the install link in the post again, you should get your hands on an auto-updating userscript (with the bug fixed).

Comment: Out of interest, have you got [the latest version](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/96426/ui-annoyances-in-the-suggested-edit-review-on-stack-overflow/122532#comment379153_122532) or not?

Comment: @Matt Check your inbox :) I have a version with the fade option. Appears as version 2.0.0.

Comment: @Matt New minor bug report: under “add to the top”, edits on tag wiki lose the name of the tag when they're acted on.

Comment: This was [tag:status-by-design] when I wrote it, but I've added that functionality in the latest (released) version.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. Now up: title quoting bug, it looks like you need to add something to escape characters in the title.

Comment: `@`Gilles: [Fixed](https://github.com/mattlunn/se-edit-queue/commit/0cbf84ccd4c8f5545be22b7096188ef46450b7aa), thanks :)